# How to print a separator if value or two consecutive rows do not match for a column

Tags: bash, awk

I have input like following and I need to put a separator between the rows if the value of the third column between two rows is different.

```
one two three four
five six three seven
eight nine ten elevel
alpha beta ten gama
tango charlie oscar bla
```

Expected result:

```
one two three four
five six three seven
=
eight nine ten elevel
alpha beta ten gama
=
tango charlie oscar bla
```

Here is what I thought would work but its not.

```
awk '{col3=$3;next} $3!=col3{$0="\n="$0;print $0}' input
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
$ awk '$3!=p && NR>1 { print "=" } { print; p=$3 }' file
one two three four
five six three seven
=
eight nine ten elevel
alpha beta ten gama
=
tango charlie oscar bla
```

Answer (score 5):

Another variant in `Awk` complementing [James's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48522200/5291015) (or just the same? written differently),

```
awk '{ if ($3 != old && NR>1) { print "=" } print; old = $3; }' file
```

The idea is basically to backup the `$3` from each line and basically if it varies in the next print the string needed. The `NR>1` is just a condition to skip printing for the first line.

Comment: It's just the same written differently (less idiomatically).

Answer (score 5):

```
$ awk 'p!=$3{if(NR>1)print "="; p=$3}1' file 
one two three four
five six three seven
=
eight nine ten elevel
alpha beta ten gama
=
tango charlie oscar bla
```

Answer (score 4):

Following `awk` may help you too in same.

***Solution 1st:*** With conditions checking and having `prev` variable in it:

```
awk 'prev!=$3 && prev{print "="} 1; {prev=$3}'  Input_file
```

***Solution 2nd:*** with use of `printf` and checking condition in it.

```
awk '{printf("%s%s",prev!=$3 && prev?"=" RS $0:$0,RS);prev=$3}' Input_file
```

Answer (score 2):

I'm going to add that the problem with your initial solution was the following:

```
{
  col3=$3;
  next;
}
```

As this was the first action, for every line, the variable `col3` would be set to field 3, before the `next` keyword would skip the second action for all lines.

Comment: Also, script won't reach print if `$3==col3`. And `$3=col3` should be in the end.